# Placing Multiple Orders in Interactive Brokers

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

This question is insipired by the following one:

[Interactive Brokers Python API - Executing multiple trades](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70701705/interactive-brokers-python-api-executing-multiple-trades)

I am trying to place 3 orders but the code is only placing 3 orders for the stock CRM rather than placing 1 order for AAPL, 1 for AMD and one for CRM. This is the code:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import *
from threading import Timer

t = ['AAPL', 'AMD', 'CRM']

n = [10, 12, 10]

class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def error(self, reqId , errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId ):
        self.nextOrderId = orderId
        self.start()

    def orderStatus(self, orderId , status, filled, remaining, avgFillPrice, permId, parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId, whyHeld, mktCapPrice):
        print("OrderStatus. Id: ", orderId, ", Status: ", status, ", Filled: ", filled, ", Remaining: ", remaining, ", LastFillPrice: ", lastFillPrice)

    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        print("OpenOrder. ID:", orderId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, "@", contract.exchange, ":", order.action, order.orderType, order.totalQuantity, orderState.status)

    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
        print("ExecDetails. ", reqId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, contract.currency, execution.execId,
              execution.orderId, execution.shares, execution.lastLiquidity)

    def start(self):
        for i in t: 
            contract = Contract()
            contract.symbol = i
            contract.secType = "STK"
            contract.exchange = "SMART"
            contract.currency = "USD"
            contract.primaryExchange = "NASDAQ"
        for j in n:
            order = Order()
            order.action = "BUY"
            order.totalQuantity = j
            order.orderType = "Market"
            self.placeOrder(self.nextOrderId, contract, order)
            self.nextOrderId = self.nextOrderId + 1
            
    


    def stop(self):
        self.done = True
        self.disconnect()

def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.nextOrderId = 0
    
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 9)

    Timer(3, app.stop).start()
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I believe my error is in the incrementation. I perhaps placed it at the wrong spot:

```
self.nextOrderId = self.nextOrderId + 1
```

I am not very good when it comes to using classes. Can someone help me correct my error?

Comment: First you make 3 contracts and then you place 3 orders.  You need to make 1 contract and then place 1 order and do this 3 times.  Your data structure should maybe be a dict with each stock having an associated quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example looping through your arrays and sending orders.

Setup the details of a contract inside a function which takes arguments, `Stock(symbol, sec_type="STK", currency="USD", exchange="ISLAND")` therefore can loop through the stock list `t` and input the ticker symbol into that function - contract object is in input in `app.placeOrder()`.

Setup a function to buy each stock `BuyStocks(app)`. A for loop going through each ticker and each quantity. Key thing and per the IB docs is to make sure incrementing the next valid order id.

Placed the trading app in its own thread as well as the main function. You could just build a full application inside main() with all logic checks for a strategy, pnl, order management, positions, executions etc..

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import Order
from ibapi.execution import *
import time
import threading

t = ['AAPL', 'AMD', 'CRM']

n = [10, 12, 10]


class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

        # define variables
        self.done = False

    # note all these functions below handle the incoming server requests.
    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString, advancedOrderRejectJson):
        super().error(reqId, errorCode, errorString, advancedOrderRejectJson)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId):
        super().nextValidId(orderId)
        self.nextValidOrderId = orderId
        print("NextValidId:", orderId)

    def orderStatus(self, orderId, status, filled, remaining, avgFillPrice, permId, parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId,
                    whyHeld, mktCapPrice):
        print("OrderStatus. Id: ", orderId, ", Status: ", status, ", Filled: ", filled, ", Remaining: ", remaining,
              ", LastFillPrice: ", lastFillPrice)

    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        super().openOrder(orderId, contract, order, orderState)

    def openOrderEnd(self):
        super().openOrderEnd()
        print("OpenOrderEnd")
        #logging.debug("Received %d openOrders", len(self.permId2ord))

    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
        super().execDetails(reqId, contract, execution)
        print("ExecDetails. ReqId:", reqId, "Symbol:", contract.symbol, "SecType:", contract.secType, "Currency:",
              contract.currency, execution)

    def execDetailsEnd(self, reqId):
        super().execDetailsEnd(reqId)
        print("ExecDetailsEnd. ReqId:", reqId)


# define some functions to help make requests to IB servers (outgoing)
## define the contract, in this case US stock
def Stock(symbol, sec_type="STK", currency="USD", exchange="ISLAND"):
    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = symbol
    contract.secType = sec_type
    contract.currency = currency
    contract.exchange = exchange
    return contract

## market order
def marketOrder(action, quantity):
    order = Order()
    order.action = action # buy or sell
    order.orderType = "MKT"
    order.totalQuantity = quantity
    order.tif = "DAY" # time in force day - cancel order if not filled - will cancel at the close
    #order.orderRef = order_ref
    order.optOutSmartRouting = False
    return order


## function to buy stocks
def BuyStocks(app):
    for i in range(0,len(t),1):
        print("This is i",i)
        print("stock is, ", t[i])
        print("qty is, ", n[i])
        app.reqIds(-1)
        time.sleep(.2)
        order_id = app.nextValidOrderId
        app.placeOrder(order_id, Stock(t[i]), marketOrder("BUY", n[i]))
        time.sleep(1)

    # disconnect when operation completed
    if i == len(t)-1:
        app.done = True
        print("Orders have been placed disconnect")
        app.disconnect()


def main(app):
    # buy function
    BuyStocks(app)


def websocket_con():
    app.run()

# setup the threads
app = TestApp()
app.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=7497, clientId=9)  # port 4002 for ib gateway paper trading/7497 for TWS paper trading
con_thread = threading.Thread(target=websocket_con, args=())  # , daemon=True
con_thread.start()
time.sleep(5) # some lag added to ensure that streaming has started

# thread for main()
MainThread = threading.Thread(target = main, args =(app,))
MainThread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(app)
```